# How do I pass command line parameters to an MSI file for a Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-10, windows-services, windows-installer

I am writing a windows service and I want to pass command line parameters for the MSI installer. The end goal is to use these command line parameters for the Service to know how to operate.

I have added an installer class as below :

```
using Quicktech.QuickteckAgentUpdaterServices.Classes;
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace Quicktech.QuickteckAgentUpdaterServices
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public partial class ProjectInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
    {
        public InstallContext myInstallContext;

        public ProjectInstaller()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }        

        private void serviceInstaller1_AfterInstall(object sender, System.Configuration.Install.InstallEventArgs e)
        {
            ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller = (ServiceInstaller)sender;                        

            using (ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(serviceInstaller.ServiceName))
            {
                sc.Start();
                
                if (Context.Parameters.Count == 0)
                {
                    Console.Write("0");
                    Global.FlagForUninstall = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("1");
                    Global.FlagForUninstall = bool.Parse(Context.Parameters["FLAGFORUNINSTALL"].ToString());
                }                    
            }
        }

        private void serviceProcessInstaller1_BeforeInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
        {
            StringDictionary myStringDictionary = myInstallContext.Parameters;
            if (myStringDictionary.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.Write("0");
                Global.FlagForUninstall = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (myInstallContext.IsParameterTrue("FlagForUninstall") == true)
                {
                    Console.Write("1");
                    Global.FlagForUninstall = bool.Parse(myInstallContext.Parameters["FlagForUninstall"].ToString());
                }
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

and I configured the Custom Actions as below :

[image]

[image]

I call the install as below :

```
c:\>msiexec.exe /i "QuickteckAgentUpdaterServiceSetup-x64.msi" /l*v "c:\temp\out.txt" FlagForUninstall=True
```

When I run the service and look at the procedure called on the On_Start event :

I have the following code :

```
if (!Global.FlagForUninstall)
```

this is set in the installer class. What am I doing wrong? Why can I not see the command line arguments?

When I look at the Log File, I see the following :

```
Property(S): FLAGFORUNINSTALL = true
```

It looks like the command line parameters are working, but I am not able to set the FlagForUninstall variable and use it in the execution of the service.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?
I do not need to set the GLOBAL.FlagforUninstall. If there is any other way to access the Installer.Context properties I am willing to go that route.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually very simple and I figured it out only minutes after posting the question.

Here is the solution :

In the install class as seen in the post I changed the AfterInstall to be the following :

```
private void serviceInstaller1_AfterInstall(object sender, System.Configuration.Install.InstallEventArgs e)
        {
            ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller = (ServiceInstaller)sender;                        

            using (ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(serviceInstaller.ServiceName))
            {                                
                if (Context.Parameters.Count == 0)
                {
                    sc.Start();
                }
                else
                {
                    sc.Start(new string[] { Context.Parameters["FLAGFORUNINSTALL"].ToString() });
                }                
            }
        }
```

by passing the value of the parameter I was looking for (Context.Parameters["FLAGFORUNINSTALL"]) as a string Arg to the service.OnStart(), I was then able to get the desired affect where I was able to say :

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {                           
            if (args != null)
            {
                if (args[0].ToString().ToUpper() == "TRUE")
                    Global.FlagForUninstall = true;
                else
                    Global.FlagForUninstall = false;
            }            
        }
```